# How to get ether from a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I'm trying to create a system with two user accounts and a contract.
I want to send ether from Account1 to Contract (**Works**).
And then I want to send ether from Contract to Account2 (**Doesn't Work**).
I'm using truffle(v4.0.4 (core: 4.0.4)), ganache(1.0.1), solidity(v0.4.18 (solc-js)) and metamask(3.13.6)
Here is my contract

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

    contract DataStore {

        address public creator;
        address UbiAccount = 0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57;  


        event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
        event LogFundsReceived(address sender, uint amount);
        event LogFundsSent(address receiver, uint amount);

        function() payable public {
            LogFundsReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
        }

        function DataStore() payable public {
            creator = msg.sender;
            LogFundsReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
        }

        function kill() public {
            selfdestruct(creator);
        }

        function SendPaymentToContract() public payable returns(bool sufficient) {
            getCurrentAddress().transfer(msg.value);
            LogFundsSent(UbiAccount, msg.value);

            return true;
        }

        function SendPaymentToUbi() public payable returns(bool sufficient) {
            UbiAccount.transfer(msg.value);
            LogFundsSent(UbiAccount, msg.value);

            return true;
        }

        function getCurrentAddress() public view returns (address){
          return this;
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
Ashutosh

Comment: You haven't explained what you're doing to try to send the ether and what goes wrong. But `SendPaymentToContract()` looks weird... it does a transfer of ether to itself. `SendPaymentToUbi()` is possibly the function you're having trouble with? If so, we'd need to see the code for the contract at address `UbiAccount`.

Comment: It looks like `UbiAccount` is just a basic account. If `UbiAccount` is meant to be 'Account2' then I can't see the problem. If it isn't then the address of 'Account2' needs to be passed to that function somehow, then the transfer function called on that address.

Comment: The idea is to have smart contract act as an Escrow service. The UbiAccount is the Account2 and is a normal account. The problem arises when I try to execute the whole scenario, then I get a `Error: invalid address`. My frontend js script goes something like this [link](https://gist.github.com/a4sh3u/81c4d06bb6055f9a8eab08481aa4376f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question if anyone faces a similar situation. In this case, my solidity contract is working fine. I made mistakes in how I was calling my solidity contract functions from my frontend. In my frontend, I wasn't setting a `web3.eth.defaultAccount`. So, when calling the functions of my contract, it didn't knew which account to use. Here is how my javascript code looks like (only pasting important stuff)

```
    var accounts;
    var account;
    window.App = {
      amount: {
        price: 0,
        time: 0
      },
      start: function() {
        var self = this;

        // Bootstrap the Ubi abstraction for Use.
        Ubi.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

        // Get the initial account balance so it can be displayed.
        web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
          if (err != null) {
            alert("There was an error fetching your accounts. Make sure MetaMask Chrome extension is installed.");
            return;
          }

          if (accs.length == 0) {
            alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
            return;
          }
          accounts = accs;
          account = accounts[0];
          web3.eth.defaultAccount = account;
        });
      },
```

After setting this up, here is how I'm calling my contract functions:

```
    pay: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.setStatus("Initiating transaction... (please wait)");

    var ds;
    Ubi.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      ds = instance;
      return ds.SendPaymentToContract({
        from: account,
        value: web3.toWei(self.amount.price, 'ether')
      }) // {from: account}  is needed to perform transactions !!!
    }).then(function() {
      console.log("Transaction to contract complete!");
      self.postToSocket("ON");

      setTimeout(function() {
        self.postToSocket("OFF");

        console.log("Stopping socket");
        return ds.SendPaymentToUbi({from: account}).then(function(e) {
          console.log(e);
          console.log("transferred from contract to ubi");
        }).catch(function(e) {
          console.log(e);
          console.log("cannnot transfer from contract to ubi");
        })
      }, self.amount.time * 1000);

      //self.refreshMapCount();
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log("Error transfering; see log.");
    });
    },
```

Hope it helps.
Regards,
Ashutosh